# Get records with duplicated date from csv file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a csv file which has records in the following format:

```
HERMES; 1981-04-11
```

I want to extract only the records where the date is not unique. I tried the nested loops seen below, but I get all records.

This is how the output should look like:

```
HERMES 1981-04-11
HERMES 1981-04-11
HERMES 1981-04-11
MARCIO 1954-03-04
MARCIO 1954-03-04
LILIAN 1970-04-19
KLEBER 1967-12-14
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
RAIMUNDO 1981-04-11
FRANCISCO 1924-03-28
RUI 0002-11-30
MARIA 1954-03-04
MARIA 1954-03-04
MANOEL 1968-03-24
JOANNA 1981-04-11
JOANNA 1981-04-11
JOANNA 1981-04-11
```

---

My code so far:

```
  for num in 0..9

    for num1 in 0..9
      dataAtual = csv[num][1]
      xatual = csv[num1][1]

      if dataAtual == xatual
        datas["nome"] = csv[num][0]
        datas["data"] = csv[num][1]
        puts datas["nome"] + " " +datas["data"]
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: Please edit to show the desired output for the example you gave.

Comment: It is still a little hard to understand what you are asking for. You want to get all records where there are at least two records with the same date? Can you give us the desired output for your example at the end?

Comment: Ok, I still don't completely understand your question. I edited my answer, please look at it and say if this is what you wanted. If not - it will be easiest if you provide both an example input and an example output for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to print the rows that have repeating dates:

```
require 'csv'

all_rows = CSV.read('test.csv', col_sep: ';')

all_rows.select do |row|
  all_rows.count { |srow| row[1].strip == srow[1].strip } > 1
end.each { |row| puts "#{row[0]} #{row[1]}" }
```

---

Here we get all rows and separate them by `;`. After that we select only the rows where the second part can be found more than once and finally we print the selected rows.

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed.Is returning all rows that have equal dates, this is exactly what i needed